# Rules for counting with parentheses C#

Tags: c#

This mabey is a dumb question but i try to count discount on a price like this:

```
newAllaVaror.Pris = System.Convert.ToDouble(
           (1 - (clientKampanj.VisaKampanj(vara.ProduktNamn) / 100)) * vara.Pris
).ToString();
```

It will look like this in reality (1-(20/100)*7.99), but my output is now 7.99 but it should be 6,392..becuse the orginal price is 7.99...
I have tried to move the parentheses but i only get 1 then..

In wich order does C# go thru the parentheses, becuse this should work right??

Comment: Integer division truncates.

Comment: `clientKampanj.VisaKampanj(vara.ProduktNamn) / 100` is suspicious does `VisaKampanj` return a `int`? If so you have integer division.

Comment: yes it returns the discount on a product this time its 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you are doing an [integer division](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f.aspx) here:

```
 (clientKampanj.VisaKampanj(vara.ProduktNamn) / 100)
```

So if you have 20/100, it will result in 0 instead of the expected 0.2 as the reminder is truncated.

You need to convert to double, one of the operands:

```
 (clientKampanj.VisaKampanj(vara.ProduktNamn) / 100.0)
```

Since @Scott pointed out your other variables are of type `decimal`, you need to convert one of the operands to that type instead:

```
 (clientKampanj.VisaKampanj(vara.ProduktNamn) / 100.0m)
```

Comment: Well now i cant use * becuse it says i can´t be used on a double..

Comment: What type is `Pris`? if it is a `decimal` use `100.0m` instead of `100.0` that makes the number a decimal instead of a double.

Comment: Thanks it works now!!

You lear something new everyday!! :D

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Thanks for the edit :) Totally messed up that one